# Can chi-squared distribution be left-skewed?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-distribution

I'm learning chi-squared distribution and know that as degree of freedom increases, right-skewed chi-squared distribution will approximate to normal distribution shape. I'm wondering can its distribution become left-skewed? How should I approach to think about this question?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, the skewness of the chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees-of-freedom is:

$$\mathbb{Skew} = \sqrt{\frac{8}{k}},$$

which is positive for all $k > 0$.  The distribution is asymptotically unskewed as $k \rightarrow \infty$, and indeed, in this case it converges to the normal distribution (in an appropriately standardised sense).

Comment: thank you @Ben! this is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Traditionally, chi-squared distributions have integer parameter values, $\nu =1, 2, 3, \dots,$ called degrees of freedom. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) for details, and for some plots of density functions--all of them right skewed, with skewness
decreasing as degrees of freedom $\nu$ increase.

However, possibly as a convenience for matching chi-squared distributions with other members of the gamma family of distributions, some software packages are programmed to
give numerical answers for positive values of $\nu$ that
are not integers:  95th percentiles of chi-squared
distributions with $\nu = .5, 1, 1.3, 2$ are about
$2.4202, 3.8414, 4.5448, 5.9915,$ respectively, according to R. [Ordinarily, you will find only the 2nd and 4th of these values in a printed table of chi-squared distributions.]

```
qchisq(.95, c(.5,1,1.3,2))
[1] 2.420232 3.841459 4.544779 5.991465
```

Here are plots of chi-squared density function for
$\nu = 1$ [black], $\nu = 2$ [dotted red], and $\nu=2$
[blue].

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "Right skewed Densities of CHISQ(1), CHIS1(1.5), CHISQ(2)"
curve(dchisq(x,1), 0,5, ylim=c(0,3), lwd=2, ylab="Density", main=hdr, n = 10001)
 curve(dchisq(x,1.5), add=T, lwd=2, lty = "dotted", col="red", n = 1001)
 curve(dchisq(x,2), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue", n = 10001)
  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

Note: There are ***generalized*** chi-squared distributions, which
*can* be left skewed; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: thank you for your response. But can you direct me to think what decides on skewness direction? is it because how density function looks like for chi-squared distribution?

Comment: The definition of skewness combined with the definition of the chi-squared pdf determine the skewness at every value of the d.f. parameter, $\nu$ for $0<\nu<\infty$ (this parameter needn't necessarily be integer); direct algebraic calculation for the chi-squared distribution gives that the moment-skewness is $\sqrt{8/\nu}$, so it's highly skew for small degrees of freedom (e.g. at $\nu=0.005$ the skewness is $40$), and less skew for large degrees of freedom (e.g. at $\nu=128$ the skewness is $\frac14$).

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you @Glen_b.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the chi-squared distribution is the sum of squares of normally distributed random variables.
When we square a number, the shape of the distribution will inevitably be skewed to the right. This is because we square negative numbers. Negative numbers will move to the positive side.

Comment: The mean will also move to the right. So it is not so clear that taking the square will increase the skewness. Imagine the distribution with the following mass density 

$$f_X(x) =\begin{cases}0.1 \quad \text{if $x=-2$}\\ 0.4 \quad \text{if $x=-1$}\\ 0.1 \quad \text{if $x=1$}\\ 0.4 \quad \text{if $x=2$}\\ 0 \quad \text{else}   \end{cases}$$ which is a right skewed distribution. It will transform into a distribution with zero skew if we square the numbers 

$$f_{X^2}(x) =\begin{cases}0.5 \quad \text{if $x=1$}\\ 0.5 \quad \text{if $x=4$}\\ 0 \quad \text{else}   \end{cases}$$

Comment: Although this argument is incorrect, it can be fixed once you observe the chi-squared(1) distribution is positively skewed--because the sum of positively skewed distributions must be positively skewed (look at the characteristic functions).

Comment: @Sextus That claim surprises me, because isn't the skewness of a non-central chi-squared distribution with $k$ df and noncentrality parameter $\lambda$ equal to $\sqrt{8}(k+3\lambda)/(k+2\lambda)^{3/2},$ which is always positive?

Comment: @whuber oops, I regarded the non-centrality parameter as possibly negative.